# Cannot select destination HD during 22.04 installation

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, sata

Nubee here - have been trying to install U Server 22.04 on an HP t620 Thin Client with 8GB RAM and 1TB SATA HD. Proceeds fine until this screen:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TaCV.jpg)

I can see the 1TB drive above the highlighted  Patriot Memory thumb drive with the installation iso. . . ***but I cannot select it with the arrow keys.***

Have searched the forum, found several ideas that made no difference (AHCI is enabled, Secure Boot disabled, etc. etc.). Tried it on a second t620, still no joy.

What am I doing wrong / what do I need to do differently???

Thanks - flyyboyy